# 3270 Screen Scrapers

Tags: terminal, screen-scraping, 3270

Looking through 2 screen scraping frameworks and thought I'd ask here for any experience. I need to recommend a framework for screen scraping an old 7032 IBM mainframe system and I'm currently looking at Inventu's Flynet (impressive, but expensive) and Zephyr's Passport HOI (cheaper and less feature rich). The goal is to encapsulate the terminal app in a webservice (WCF) and let less than 50 concurrent user access the service. Any ideas or recommendations?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember well the [Expect tool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect) can be useful. Other resources are:

- [x3270 script](http://x3270.bgp.nu/x3270-script.html)
- [Jagacy 3270](http://freshmeat.net/projects/jagacy3270)

Comment: I apoint you the answer - was however looking for .NET specific frameworks - We settled with Zephyr's solution, but did consider a BizTalk implementation.